# Find an array that have only the not same object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array:

```
var objArray = [
   { id: 0, name: ‘Object 0’, otherProp: ‘321’ },
   { id: 1, name: ‘O1’, otherProp: ‘648’ },
   { id: 2, name: ‘Another Object’, otherProp: ‘850’ },
   { id: 3, name: ‘Almost There’, otherProp: ‘046’ },
   { id: 4, name: ‘Last Obj’, otherProp: ‘984’ },
   { id: 0, name: ‘Object 0’, otherProp: ‘321’ }
];
```

here the id 0 add twice. I only want an array that not have the same objects.

expected output:

```
a = [
   { id: 0, name: ‘Object 0’, otherProp: ‘321’ },
   { id: 1, name: ‘O1’, otherProp: ‘648’ },
   { id: 2, name: ‘Another Object’, otherProp: ‘850’ },
   { id: 3, name: ‘Almost There’, otherProp: ‘046’ },
   { id: 4, name: ‘Last Obj’, otherProp: ‘984’ }]
```

How do I do this in JavaScript.

Comment: Please also add the expected output.

Comment: You should add the code you've tried as a [mcve].

Comment: It's reasonable to create the array without doubles at the beginning.

Comment: What should happen if a duplicate ID is used? Don't insert the entry? Remove the previous entry?

Comment: You are considering duplicates using `id` only ?

Comment: George Bailey this only work for string not for objects

Comment: yes Sudhir Ojha

Comment: @Hasibul- Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ts53v7o2/1/

Comment: @Hasibul- By the way, I don't think your question is duplicate of question about an array of strings. What a community...

Comment: @Alexander yet it's trivial to adapt the code for arbitrary objects by comparing the property you want to consider unique (`id` in this case) instead of the item itself. We don't need a different question for each different case when it is all the same logic in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the array by looking for the `id` in a `Set`.

```js
var array = [{ id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321' }, { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: '648' }, { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850' }, { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046' }, { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '984' }, { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321' }],
    seen = new Set,
    result = array.filter(({ id }) => !seen.has(id) && seen.add(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina Scholz :) it's working